# AudioQueueStart() method can not play music in ios4 background

Tags: ios4, audioqueue, audio-player

In the iphone 3.x platform, I use AudioQueueStart method to play music, but on ios4 platform, once the program into the background,then no sound, but I notice that the app is still running in background, I've added into the info.list UIBackgroundModes/Audio and  applicationDidEnterBackground methods

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is that the `AudioSession` is active first.

In my case, I had previously set the session to inactive between song changes before starting a new song:

```
AudioSessionSetActive(false);
```

Once I removed this `AudioQueueStart` works just fine from the background.